# Using If statement in a MVC Razor View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razor-2

In the following code,

If I use "@If" statement ,I get the following compile code error as " The name 'grid' does not exist in the current context.

```
@if (Model.SModel != null)

{

@{ 
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.SModel);

 }

 }

 else
 {
}

@grid.GetHtml()
```

,

But the code compiles without the "If" statement.For example

```
@{ 
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.SModel);

}
@grid.GetHtml().
```

What is the syntactical error in using If else statement

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`grid` isn't declared outside of the scope of your `if` statment.

Try this instead:

```
@if (Model.SModel != null) {
    WebGrid(Model.SModel).GetHtml()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

```
@if (Model.SModel != null)
{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.SModel);
    grid.GetHtml()
}
else
{
}
```

Comment: `grid` doesn't exist outside of the `if` statement

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use @{} inside @if. Write like this:

```
@if (Model.SModel != null)
{
WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.SModel)
}
```

Comment: `grid` won't exist outside of the `if` statement